# Singleton class in Kotlin with init

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton

I just to wish clarify some methodology using singletons in Kotlin.

I have this class:

```
class TestClass {

companion object {
    val instance = TestClass()

    fun runSync2() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Running sync2")
    }
    
    init {
        Log.d("TAG", "Init companion")
    }
}

init {
    Log.d("TAG", "Init class")
}

fun runSync1() {
    Log.d("TAG", "Running sync1")
 }
}
```

And this test functions:

```
1. TestClass.instance.runSync1()
2. TestClass.runSync2()
3. TestClass().runSync1()
```

1. When calling function 1 twice, init inside companion object will be called once. So only one instance of TestClass is created and run runSync1() twice, correct?
2. When calling function 2 twice, init inside companion object will be called once. So only one instance of TestClass is created and run runSync2() twice, correct? So what is the difference between 1 and 2?
3. When calling function 2 twice, 2 instances of TestClass crated, 2 init inside class will run and 2 runSync1 will run independently?

Can you please provide more clarification and correct the wrong parts?

Comment: there is no `function1` or `function2` in your code, use exact names, so that we can understand the problem better

Comment: There is no actual problem, just clarification. As you can see in the section "And this test functions" marked 1,2,3. When mentioning "function 1" it refers to function marked as 1 -> "TestClass.instance.runSync1()" ant etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When understanding the companion objects one thing to remember is that

***A companion object is initialized when the corresponding class is loaded (resolved) that matches the semantics of a Java static initializer.***

So the `init` block inside the `companion` object will be executed only once, when the `TestClass` is being loaded, same goes with the property named `instance`, it will be assigned an object of `TestClass` only once at `class` load time.

To better understand this you can look at your code converted to java, which will look something like

```
public final class TestClass {

    // Property of companion object and the init block are now part of TestClass
    private static final TestClass instance = new TestClass();

    static {
       Log.d("TAG", "Init companion");
    }

    public static final TestClass.Companion Companion = new TestClass.Companion((DefaultConstructorMarker)null);

    public final void runSync1() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Running sync1");
    }

    public TestClass() {
        Log.d("TAG", "Init class");
    }


    public static final class Companion {
        public final TestClass getInstance() {
            return TestClass.instance;
        }

        public final void runSync2() {
            Log.d("TAG", "Running sync2");
        }

        private Companion() { }

        public Companion(DefaultConstructorMarker $constructor_marker) {
            this();
        }
    }
}
```